# check mybb password throw App login with CURL

Tags: php, curl, authentication, mybb

I use curl protocol on my application.

The users in my forum only allow to use this App after logging throw this appto his account in my forum but I have a problem on php side with password checking.
I think there is a problem on my php code because with correct user and password I have this error:
(incorrect username and/or password).

```
<?php
// Database info
$MySQL_Host = "localhost";
$MySQL_User = "lol";
$MySQL_Pass = "lol2";
$MySQL_DB = "lol3";
$tbl_name = "mybb_users";

function ParsePost( )
{
    $username = '';
    $password = '';

    $post = file_get_contents( "php://input" );

    $post = str_replace( "&", " ", $post );

    sscanf( $post, "%s  %s", $username, $password );

    return array( 'user' => $username,
                  'pass' => $password
                );
}

function mysql_fetch_full_result_array( $result )
{
    $table_result = array();
    $r = 0;

    if( $result === true )
    {
        return $result;
    }

    if( mysql_num_rows( $result ) == 0 )
    {
        return $result;
    }

    while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) )
    {
        $arr_row = array();
        $c = 0;

        while ( $c < mysql_num_fields( $result ) )
        {       
            $col = mysql_fetch_field( $result, $c );   
            $arr_row[ $col -> name ] = $row[ $col -> name ];           
            $c++;
        }   

        $table_result[ $r ] = $arr_row;
        $r++;
    }   

    return $table_result;
}

class DWAuth
{
    var $keys;

    function AddDWValue( $val )
    {
        $this->keys[] = $val;
    }

    function GetAuthString( )
    {
        $result = "";

        foreach( $this->keys as $c )
        {
            $result .= $c."#";
        }

        return $result;
    }
}

class DB
{
    var $connection;
    var $started;

    function start()
    {
        global $MySQL_Host, $MySQL_User, $MySQL_Pass, $MySQL_DB;

        $this->connection = mysql_connect("$MySQL_Host", "$MySQL_User", "$MySQL_Pass");
        mysql_select_db("$MySQL_DB", $this->connection );
    }

    function query( $query )
    {
        $result = mysql_query( $query, $this->connection );

        if( $result )
        {
            return mysql_fetch_full_result_array( $result );
        }
        else
        {
            return $result;
        }
    }

    function end()
    {
        mysql_close( $this->connection );
    }

    function isStarted()
    {
        return $started;
    }
}

class Login
{

    function CheckLogin( $username, $password )
    {
        $db = new DB();
        $db->start();

        $query = "SELECT id, password, email FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".md5( $password )."';";

        $result = $db->query( $query );

        $db->end();

        if( $result == false )
            return false;
            fwrite($fh, $result);
            fclose($fh);


        if( md5(md5($row['salt']).md5($password)) == $result[ 0 ][ 'password' ] )
        {
            return array( 'id' => $result[ 0 ][ 'id' ],
                          'mail' => $result[ 0 ][ 'email' ],
                          'user' => $username
                        );
        }
    }
}

$packet = new DWAuth();
$result = ParsePost();

if( ( empty( $result[ 'user' ] ) ) || ( empty( $result[ 'pass' ] ) ) )
{
    $packet->AddDWValue( "fail" );
    $packet->AddDWValue( "Username and/or password is empty." );
    $packet->AddDWValue( 1 );
    $packet->AddDWValue( "Anonymous" );
    $packet->AddDWValue( "anonymous@example.com" );
    $packet->AddDWValue( 0 );

    echo $packet->GetAuthString();

    die();
}

$login = new Login();
$result = $login->CheckLogin( $result[ 'user' ], $result[ 'pass' ] );

if( $result == false )
{
    $packet->AddDWValue( "fail" );
    $packet->AddDWValue( "incorrect username and/or password." );
    $packet->AddDWValue( 1 );
    $packet->AddDWValue( "Anonymous" );
    $packet->AddDWValue( "anonymous@example.com" );
    $packet->AddDWValue( 0 );
}
else
{
    $sessionID = md5( rand() );
    // How to make the return
    $packet->AddDWValue( "ok" ); // fail or ok
    $packet->AddDWValue( "Success." ); // Success or error
    $packet->AddDWValue( $result[ 'id' ] ); // UserID
    $packet->AddDWValue( $result[ 'user' ] ); // Username
    $packet->AddDWValue( $result[ 'mail' ] ); // email
    $packet->AddDWValue( $sessionID ); // sessionID

    $db = new DB();
    $db->start();

    $query = "UPDATE users SET sid='".$sessionID."' WHERE id=".$result[ 'id' ];

    $result = $db->query( $query );
    $db->end();
}

echo $packet->GetAuthString();

?>
```

Comment: Hi, this is way too much code and way too little specific information to help you. Can you try and pinpoint the problem a bit more? What exactly goes on where?

Comment: I have problem on "class Login" actually i don't know mybb use what method for coding password for that reason i can't use php code to check password is correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

I know this might be a bit too late, but I believe the problem is within your query itself.

Change:

```
$query = "SELECT id, password, email FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".md5( $password )."';";
```

to

```
$query = "SELECT uid, password, email FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='".$username."' OR email='".$username."';";
```

Remember to sanitise your strings before using them with a database!